# VBA code to insert column and formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file where I need to delete certain columns. I then need to insert a column called 'positive values' and add a formula so that only the positive values from another column are picked up in this new column.

So far I have pieced together the following code to delete the columns I do not need, but I am stuck at how to insert a new column next to an existing column called "net" and then have this column only show the positive values from column net in the relevant cells.

**Current code**

```
Sub ArrayLoop()
  Dim ColumnsToRemove As Variant
  Dim vItem As Variant
  Dim A As Range

  Sheets("sheet 1").Select

  ColumnsToRemove = Array("acronym", "valueusd", "value gbp")
  For Each vItem In ColumnsToRemove
    Set A = Rows(8).Find(What:=vItem, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    Debug.Print vItem, Not A Is Nothing

    If Not A Is Nothing Then A.EntireColumn.Delete
  Next
End Sub
```

Currently I manually insert the new column and enter the formula max(E9,0) so the new column either shows 0 or a value if the value in the other column is greater than 0. Is it possible to automate this part as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please go back over your Q's title and narrative to decide whether you are speaking os a row or column?

Comment: Have done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Insertion locate the cell and issue:

```
If Not A Is Nothing Then A.EntireColumn.Insert
```

To insert a formula, use `cell.formula=` with the coresponding string value, e.g.

```
Cells(1, A.column - 1).Formula = "=max(" & cells(9, A.column - 2).Address & ",0)"
```

Note A as a range of the found value will shift to the right when inserting a column that's why you need `- 1` nad `- 2` in cell references.

Comment: Thank you. That has allowed me to add the column I need. With the formula how can I get it to loop so it works for every cell where there is a value. Currently it will apply to the top cell only and then stop. My data set is approx 6000 lines long.